# Next13 Dockerfile can't find server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, next.js, dockerfile

Using this official Dockerfile from Next with they show in their examples

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I get the following error when trying to build the app using a Dockerfile and docker-compose

```
b78-client-1  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
b78-client-1  |   throw err;
b78-client-1  |   ^
b78-client-1  | 
b78-client-1  | Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
b78-client-1  |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
b78-client-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
b78-client-1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
b78-client-1  |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
b78-client-1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
b78-client-1  |   requireStack: []
b78-client-1  | }
b78-client-1  | 
b78-client-1  | Node.js v18.16.0
b78-client-1 exited with code 1
```

This is my next.config.js

```
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  reactStrictMode: false,
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  output: "standalone",

});
```

I'm not using the beta app directory
If I try to run the image with out the CMD ["node", "server.js"], create a container with the image and enter with SH, then run the the server.js with node it starts up fine

```
  ~/Desktop/b78 on   master !4 ❯ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh nextjsimg
/app $ ls
node_modules  package.json  public        server.js
/app $ ls public
assets       favicon.svg
/app $ ls -a
.             ..            .next         node_modules  package.json  public        server.js
/app $ ls .next
BUILD_ID                      package.json                  react-loadable-manifest.json  routes-manifest.json          static
build-manifest.json           prerender-manifest.json       required-server-files.json    server
/app $ node server.js
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `CMD ["node", "server.js"]` applies into wrong path. U should change directory before running server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).